# Alter SQL Server Database without using TSQL or Designer

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ssms

For a project I am working on, I need to ALTER several existing tables, views, and stored procedures in a SQL Server database.  Then I need to write C# code to use the new features.  In the past I have used SQL Server Management Studio to either:

- use the table designer
- or write TSQL

In fact, those are the 2 options given by MS to [Add Columns to a Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190238.aspx).

**Is there a better/ more modern way of doing this?**  SSMS does not have intellisense and does not create "change" scripts for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx)** in Visual Studio.  You need VS 2012 and an installation of SQL Server to use it.  In VS, you can connect to a database using "SQL Server Object Explorer".  It has some awesome features:

- You can edit the object in the designer or in TSQL (They stay in sync)
- You can click "update" to modify the database or generate a change SQL script to run later.
- It supports intellisense!  Woot!
- You can right click to use snippets to easily generate triggers, procedures, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the SMO API to alter database objects: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.aspx

SMO provides a full object-oriented API to most things in SQL server. To add a column to a table its as simple as:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

var server = new Server("localhost");
var database = server.Databases["db"];
var table = database.Tables["table"];

var newColumn = new Column(table, "new", DataType.Int);
table.Columns.Add(newColumn);
table.Alter();
```